# filtering off rows in a dataset using specific conditions

Tags: r

I have a small follow-up question to a previous one answered here. With a dummy dataset as included below, I would like to filter off rows in which one or more of the samples (denoted S1, S2, S3, S4 in the dataset) has only "1" and "0", as well as all rows where the samples have only 1", "0" and "."

| ID | Pos | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 22 | . | 1 | 0 | . |
| B | 21 | 1 | 0 | . | 1 |
| C | 50 | 0 | . | . | . |
| D | 11 | . | 1 | . | . |
| E | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| F | 14 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| G | 10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

In other words, I want to keep only those rows that either has "1" in all the samples, or "0" in all samples, or "1" and "." in all samples, or lastly those with "0" and "." such that at the end, I have the final dataset looking as below

| ID | Pos | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 50 | 0 | . | . | . |
| D | 11 | . | 1 | . | . |
| E | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| F | 14 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I am trying to do this in R and I request any suggestions from you.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  filter(pmap_lgl(., ~ { x <- c(...)[-c(1, 2)];
  !all(c(".", "0", "1") %in% x) & !all(c("0", "1") %in% x)}))

  ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
1  C  50  0  .  .  .
2  D  11  .  1  .  .
3  E  13  0  0  0  0
4  F  14  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Many thanks! The suggestions work great as I wanted. Kind regards.

Comment: Oh you're welcome, glad it helped. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2):

Keep rows where all values within S columns are different from "0" or "1" and have at least one "1" or "0" (to remove rows with only ".").

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

setDT(df)[
  pmap_lgl(
    mget(str_subset(names(df), "^S[0-9]+$")), 
    ~(all(c(...) != "1") || all(c(...) != "0")) && any(c(...) != ".")
  )
]

   ID Pos S1 S2 S3 S4
1:  C  50  0  .  .  .
2:  D  11  .  1  .  .
3:  E  13  0  0  0  0
4:  F  14  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

dieveed, it's best if you provide your data with R's `dput` function.

The way to do this in the tidyverse would be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), Pos = c("22", 
"21", "50", "11", "13", "14", "10"), S1 = c(".", "1", "0", ".", 
"0", "1", "1"), S2 = c("1", "0", ".", "1", "0", "1", "0"), S3 = c("0", 
".", ".", ".", "0", "1", "0"), S4 = c(".", "1", ".", ".", "0", 
"1", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df %>%
  filter(
    if_all(matches("^S"), ~ . == 0) |
      if_all(matches("^S"), ~ . == 1) |
      if_all(matches("^S"), ~ . != 0) |
      if_all(matches("^S"), ~ . != 1)
    )

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  ID    Pos   S1    S2    S3    S4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 C     50    0     .     .     .    
2 D     11    .     1     .     .    
3 E     13    0     0     0     0    
4 F     14    1     1     1     1
```